# Firebase Auth for Web -- why is there no `MicrosoftAuthProvider` or `AzureAuthProvider`?

Tags: firebase-authentication

I'm confused how to most easily configure Microsoft's auth provider using Firebase.

I've configured `GoogleAuthProvider` and `GithubAuthProvider` as sign-in providers for Firebase Auth:

[https://console.firebase.google.com/project/${PROJECT}/authentication/providers](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/$%7BPROJECT%7D/authentication/providers)

I've added Firebase auth to my app and reviewing [Easily add sign-in to your Web app with Firebase UI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/firebaseui)

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.5/firebase-app.js"/>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.5/firebase-auth.js"/>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/4.8.0/firebase-ui-auth.js"/>

<link
  type="text/css"
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/4.8.0/firebase-ui-auth.css"
</head>

<body>
<h2>App</h2>
<hr/>
<div id="firebaseui-auth-container"></div>
<div id="loader">Loading...</div>
<script>
// Initialize Firebase
var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "...",
    authDomain: "...",
    projectId: "...",
    storageBucket: "...",
    messagingSenderId: "...",
    appId: "..."
  };
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Initialize the FirebaseUI Widget using Firebase.
var ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());

var uiConfig = {
    callbacks: {
        signInSuccessWithAuthResult: function(authResult, redirectUrl) {
            return true;
        },
        uiShown: function() {
            document.getElementById('loader').style.display = 'none';
        }
    },
    signInFlow: 'popup',
    signInSuccessUrl: '/app',
    signInOptions: [
        firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        firebase.auth.GithubAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        //firebase.auth.MicrosoftAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
    ],
    tosUrl: "/tos",
    privatePolicyUrl: "/policy",
};

ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', uiConfig);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This works for Google and GitHub but I'm unclear why there's no Microsoft|Azure variant:

```js
# Either
firebase.auth.MicrosoftAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
# Or
firebase.auth.AzureAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
```

Microsoft is obviously available as one of the providers.

It's not listed as an implementor of [`firebase.AuthProvider'](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.AuthProvider) and is omitted from [OAuth providers (Google, Facebook, Twitter and GitHub)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/firebaseui#oauth_providers_google_facebook_twitter_and_github) but it does have its [Authenticate using Microsoft with JavaScript](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/microsoft-oauth) but this approach -- even though it confirms it uses the Firebase JavaScript SDK to handle the OAuth flow -- is different:

```
var provider = new firebase.auth.OAuthProvider('microsoft.com');
```

My JavaScript fu is not very strong and I'd appreciate guidance in how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the solution to handle Microsoft requires an additional setup that is not available as a drop-in solution and requires an additional setup on the user's behalf. as such, it cannot be supported directly and falls into the custom auth solution like `yahoo.com`.

It could be changed if there is a feature request but it would have to fall under unique conditions for Microsoft to receive the level of special treatment